# Type Error in Haskell regarding Real type

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, so I dont quite understand what is going on here, other than it is a type error with the return value or values that I am using.  Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
type Point a = (a,a)

-- Determine the true distance between two points.
distance :: (Real a, Floating b) => Point a -> Point a -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)

* Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          distance :: forall a b.
                      (Real a, Floating b) =>
                      Point a -> Point a -> b
        at mod11PA.hs:12:13
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          distance :: forall a b.
                      (Real a, Floating b) =>
                      Point a -> Point a -> b
        at mod11PA.hs:12:13
    * In the expression: sqrt ((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2)
      In an equation for `distance':
          distance (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = sqrt ((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2)
    * Relevant bindings include
        y2 :: a (bound at mod11PA.hs:13:22)
        x2 :: a (bound at mod11PA.hs:13:19)
        y1 :: a (bound at mod11PA.hs:13:14)
        x1 :: a (bound at mod11PA.hs:13:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most number functions in the standard library that aren't explicitly conversion functions, `sqrt` returns a value of the same type of its argument:

```
GHCi> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

If you replace `a` with `b`, your function will pass the type checker:

```
distance :: (Floating b) => Point b -> Point b -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
```

If you really need values with types that are instances of `Real` in your arguments, you can use `realToFrac` to do the necessary conversions:

```
GHCi> :t realToFrac
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

```
distance :: (Real a, Floating b) => Point a -> Point a -> b
distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt (realToFrac ((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2))
```

P.S.: Note that `Real` and `Floating` aren't types, but classes. We say, for instance, that `Double`, a concrete type, has an instance of the `Floating` class (or, less formally, that `Double` is a `Floating`).

Comment: For this project we aren't allowed to change the method signatures.  So I have to use realToFrac?  Would I just call realToFrac on the whole line?

Comment: @JohnOchs The easiest way is applying it to the value you give to `sqrt`. See my edit to the answer.